# Select div using wildcard ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, prototypejs

How to select a div using it's ID but with a widcard?

If the DIV's ID is `statusMessage_1098`, I would like to select it in some way like `document.getElementById('statusMessage_*')`.

This is because until the page is generated, I don't know the suffix of the ID and only one such ID will be present in a page. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do this

```
$("div[id^='statusMessage_']")
```

See **[attributeStartsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith#attributevalue)**

***Edit - with class name selector***

If you can use a class name then you can use something like this

```
$$('div.myDivClass');
```

gets all div elements with class 'myDivClass'

Comment: Thanks for that solution. But unfortunately, I don't use jQuery. But Prototype is OK. Any equivalent of this in Prototype? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with prototype.

Comment: Prototype supports the same selector, just use $$: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar

Comment: To clarify this, to do what the OP wanted in Prototype, the command is:

$$("div[id^='statusMessage_']")

Comment: I think this solution is unhelpful. The author doesn't seem to ask for a jQuery solution but for a standard JS solution.

Answer (score 27):

Just thought it was worth updating the thread with a more recent way of doing this in JavaScript as was still coming up in searches.

```
document.querySelector("[id^='statusMessage_']");
```

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) lists it can be used on IDs from IE8 and great support in other browsers.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for in 2018

Comment: Thanks for this answer. If one needs to get multiple elements `document.querySelectorAll()` can be used.

Answer (score 22):

### Wildcard Solution based on element id attribute

Yes it is possible. This answers your question directly without relying on third-party JavaScript or APIs or attributes other than the id of the element. Also you don't have to use class=

**Custom Method Call Example**

```
// Uses JavaScript regex features to search on id= attribute
var arrMatches = document.getElementsByRegex('^statusMessage_.*');
```

This gets an array containing all elements having an id starting with "statusMessage_" (even nested ones).

**Implementation Example - reusable and generic**

Here's an implementation for the `getElementsByRegex` function that searches the DOM for the given regex, starting from `document`. It's attached to the document object for convenience and according to expected behaviour.

```
<head>
<script>
// Called as: document.getElementsByRegex("pattern").
// Returns an array of all elements matching a given regular expression on id.
// 'pattern' argument is a regular expression string.
//
document['getElementsByRegex'] = function(pattern){
   var arrElements = [];   // to accumulate matching elements
   var re = new RegExp(pattern);   // the regex to match with

   function findRecursively(aNode) { // recursive function to traverse DOM
      if (!aNode) 
          return;
      if (aNode.id !== undefined && aNode.id.search(re) != -1)
          arrElements.push(aNode);  // FOUND ONE!
      for (var idx in aNode.childNodes) // search children...
          findRecursively(aNode.childNodes[idx]);
   };

   findRecursively(document); // initiate recursive matching
   return arrElements; // return matching elements
};
</script>
</head>
```

There are likely more efficient implementations but this one provides a start. The body of the function can be replaced with other algorithms according to taste.

**Test the Code**

Finally, test it using an HTML blurb having nested elements like this

```
<body>

<div id="statusMessage_1">1</div>
<div id="statusMessage_2">2
    <div id="content">other stuff</div>
    <div id="statusMessage_3">3</div>
</div>

<script>
   // a quick test to see if you get the expected result.
   var arrMatches = document.getElementsByRegex('^statusMessage_.*');
   alert('found ' + arrMatches.length + ' matches - expected 3.')
</script>
```

This HTML block contains three elements starting with `id="statusMessage_`; therefore the alert test will say

> "found 3 matches - expected 3"

**Addendum Info for Variations**

If you want to restrict the search to only div elements or some other kind of specific element then you will want to inject the following `getElementByTagName` code into the algorithm to restrict the set of elements searched against.

```
var arrDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); // pull all divs from the doc
```

You might want to modify the generic algorithm by passing the tag name in a second argument to filter on before searching commences like this

```
var arrMatches = document.getElementsByRegex('^statusMessage_.*', 'div');
```

Answer (score 2):

In jquery, the easiest way is to assign a class for every div let say 'statusMessage'
something like:

```
<div id="statusMessage_<%=someid%>" class="statusMessage">...</div>
```

To get them all:

```
$('.statusMessage')  // or $('div.statusMessage') //or $('div[id^=statusMessage_]')
```

Without jquery:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
   if(divs[i].id.indexOf('statusMessage_')==0){
      //do stuff here for every divs[i]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now that sparked an idea. I can use a classname for it and access it using that classname.

Answer (score 1):

```
function switch2 (elementid)
{
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for ( var i = 0; divs[i]; i++ )
  {
    if (divs[i].id.indexOf("statusMessage_") == 0)
    {
      document.getElementById (divs[i].id).style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Just replace `document.getElementById (divs[i].id).style.display = "none";` with whatever CSS you want to apply to all divs that have an id that starts with *statusMessage_*.

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2020:

Using jQuery you can do this

```
$("div[id^=statusMessage_]")
```

**Omit the single quotes.

I also often add a variable to the end:

```
$("div[id^=statusMessage_" + id + "]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're populating it but if it's from the code behind you could try something like:

```
document.getElementById('statusMessage_<%= generatedID %>')
```

where generatedID is the ID generated from the code behind.

Comment: Generating it the first time is OK for me. But calling it in subsequent javascript is what comes as a problem. That's because the AJAX calls will modify the div after some time and the ID may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Usual way to do this within css is to give the elements a class 'statusMessage' in addition to their unique ids. Then you can create a css rule with a selector that will affect all elements with that class. Eg

```
 .statusMessage {color: red;}
```

Remember that elements can have more than one class. Eg

```
<p id="id123" class="class1 class2">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jQuery then there is another easier way to do this:

Assign a **`class`** - for an example name it "message", and use the following:

```
function getElementsByClass(searchClass,node,tag) {
    var classElements = new Array();
    if ( node == null )
        node = document;
    if ( tag == null )
        tag = '*';
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var elsLen = els.length;
    var pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)"+searchClass+"(\\s|$)");
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < elsLen; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(els[i].className) ) {
            classElements[j] = els[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return classElements;
}
```

Here how you call it:

```
var messages = getElementsByClass("message");

for(var index=0; index < messages.length; index++) {
 // prompt the content of the div
 //alert(message[index].innerText);
}
```