# Find id by pattern (Without jquery or 3rd party libraries)

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I have a button:

```
<button id="btn:1:uniquenamehere">btn</button>
```

the number in the middle sometimes changes due to other frameworks internal workings. I need to be able to find this button no matter the number in the middle. So I need to find it by pattern where only the middle number will change. So I need something like this:

```
document.getElementById("btn:*:uniquenamehere")
```

I saw ways of doing it using jquery, but I can't use 3rd party libraries. How can I do this with pure javascript?

Comment: Can you not just add a class to those buttons and then look them up by their class name ?

Comment: Take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12566888/1685196) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6991494/1685196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="uniquenamehere"]');
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y5uyqhkw/)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you'd like to fool around a bit, this is a good (if not as efficient) way:

```
function getButton (buttonid) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i += 1) {
        if (buttons[i].id.slice(buttons[i].id.length - buttonid.length) === buttonid) {
            return buttons[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b00t/15sxtnv0/)**