# How to get id value from tag div using javascript and regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this sample code:

```
<div id="click-test-1">Click test 1</div>
<div id="click-test-2">Click test 2</div>
```

In jQuery I use this code:

```
jQuery("div[id^=\'click-test\']").click(...);
```

How can I get the same thing in basic JavaScript?

Comment: In a newer browser you can use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: By "in javascript" do you mean "without jQuery"?

Comment: @ruakh: yes, I don't using Jquery

Comment: Already been solved. Check out this answer

[Wildcard Solution based on element id attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1938465/861940)

Answer (score 5):

So you're looking to do this in vanilla Javascript, without the jQuery library loaded?  Because jQuery *is* Javascript.

If you don't have to worry about supporting older browsers (notably IE7 and under), you can use `document.querySelector` (to get a single matching element) or `document.querySelectorAll` (to get an array of all matching elements) to look up elements by CSS selectors:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=\'click-test\']")
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
    elems[i].click()  
    // Note that click() is also browser/element-type-dependent without jQuery
}
```

If you do have to worry about supporting other browsers, then there's really no way but to do a `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` and then loop over the result checking each element's id against a regex.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; ++i) {
    if (elems[i].id.match(/^click-test/)) {
        elems[i].click()
    }
}
```

In the particular case of looking for a prefix, you can use Gabe's substring test instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex if you're just looking to get all `<div>`'s that have an id that starts with some string... You could simply do it like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zHy2/)

```
var children = document.body.getElementsByTagName('div');
var elements = [], child;
for (var i = 0, length = children.length; i < length; i++) {
   child = children[i];
   if (child.id.indexOf("click-test") == 0)
   // if you want to use a regex, just replace this condition with
   // if (child.id.match(/^click-test/))
      elements.push(child);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the direct answer to your question, but why don't you just use classes? getElementByClassName will get the job done.

```
<div id="click-test-1" class="click_me">Click test 1</div>
<div id="click-test-2" class="click_me">Click test 2</div>
```

Something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName('click_me');

for(var i=0, leng=collection.length; i<leng; i++)
{
    collection[i].click();
}
```

Maybe I'm not taking into account your whole context, but I would say using id for grouping elements is a bad practice.