# get dynamic id by partial match

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to get the id of an element that will be partially dynamic every time, separated by a colon.  here is an example of what i mean:

```
<input type="text" id="j_id235:keyValue" />
```

the part after the colon is always the same, i need to somehow search by that only.

i've tried this:

```
console.log(document.querySelector('[id^=:keyValue]').id)
```

but am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
>   '[id^=:keyValue]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I think it's jsf type id and you have forgot to give id in jsf component which remove the requirement to make partial match

Comment: This should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938294/select-div-using-wildcard-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:` is a special character in selectors. If you want to match an attribute value that contains special characters, you have to quote the value.

Also note that `^=` is the *prefix* selector. You probably want the *suffix* selector:

```
[id$=":keyValue"]
```

If you know the element type, it would probably make sense to use that as well:

```
input[id$=":keyValue"]
```

More information can be found in the [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).