# use wildcard to find specific ID using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard

I want to run a script where I can specifically select ID tag where parameters are 
 **_string_n_n** 
where *'_string'* = release (in this case) and *'n'* = are numbers # 
e.g. **_release_8_3**

Here's my code... where I wan to run the script and get content of tag where ID matches _string_n_n

```
<div class="sect2">
      <h3 id="_release_8_3">Release 8.3</h3>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_4_to_take_a_look_at_manifest">QA TEST release 1.2.4 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.4.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_3_to_take_a_look_at_manifest">QA TEST release 1.2.3 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.3.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_release_8_3_1">QA release 8.3.1</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-8.2.6.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Bugs <a href="link">fixed in this release</a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Package updates:</p>
              <div class="literalblock">
                <div class="content">
                  <pre>user-portal 8.2</pre>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Database migration scripts to run:</p>
              <div class="literalblock">
                <div class="content">
                  <pre>none</pre>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sect2">
      <h3 id="_release_8_2">Release 8.2</h3>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_4_to_take_a_look_at_manifest_2">QA TEST release 1.2.4 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.4.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_3_to_take_a_look_at_manifest_2">QA TEST release 1.2.3 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.3.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sect3">
        <h4 id="_qa_release_8_2_6">QA release 8.2.6</h4>
        <div class="ulist">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <p><a href="release-manifest-8.2.6.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Bugs <a href="link">fixed in this release</a></p>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Package updates:</p>
              <div class="literalblock">
                <div class="content">
                  <pre>user-portal 8.2</pre>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <p>Database migration scripts to run:</p>
              <div class="literalblock">
                <div class="content">
                  <pre>none</pre>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ..........what?

Comment: So do it?  I mean, you can create a selector string from other strings.  What about this confuses you?

Comment: `document.querySelector(\`_${string}_${num1}_${num2}\`)`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox missing the # or '.'

Comment: `$("#_" + release + "_" + version")`

Comment: Can you change how the html is generated?  eg `<h4 data-release='uat' data-version='8.3.1'>` ?

Comment: This appears to have already been answered in the question [Select div using wildcard ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1938300/7427606)

Comment: @ChrisTyler this question appears to be about selecting a div using *multiple* wildcards, but that answer could be adapted using `.filter`

Answer (score 2):

Select all elements with an ID containing the following string (in this case `_release_`:

`document.querySelectorAll("[id*='_release_']");`

In jQuery:  `$("[id*='_release_']")`

Here are [more wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714421/1451422) if you need a different reaction.

```js
console.dir(document.querySelectorAll("[id*='_release_']"))
```

```html
<div class="sect2">
  <h3 id="_release_8_3">Release 8.3</h3>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_4_to_take_a_look_at_manifest">QA TEST release 1.2.4 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.4.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_3_to_take_a_look_at_manifest">QA TEST release 1.2.3 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.3.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_release_8_3_1">QA release 8.3.1</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-8.2.6.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Bugs <a href="link">fixed in this release</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Package updates:</p>
          <div class="literalblock">
            <div class="content">
              <pre>user-portal 8.2</pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Database migration scripts to run:</p>
          <div class="literalblock">
            <div class="content">
              <pre>none</pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sect2">
  <h3 id="_release_8_2">Release 8.2</h3>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_4_to_take_a_look_at_manifest_2">QA TEST release 1.2.4 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.4.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_test_release_1_2_3_to_take_a_look_at_manifest_2">QA TEST release 1.2.3 (to take a look at manifest)</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-1.2.3.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sect3">
    <h4 id="_qa_release_8_2_6">QA release 8.2.6</h4>
    <div class="ulist">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><a href="release-manifest-8.2.6.html">Release Manifest</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Bugs <a href="link">fixed in this release</a></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Package updates:</p>
          <div class="literalblock">
            <div class="content">
              <pre>user-portal 8.2</pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p>Database migration scripts to run:</p>
          <div class="literalblock">
            <div class="content">
              <pre>none</pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are going to do this, consider instead using a class for better performance.

Comment: Taplar is right, it would also be less of a headache for the next developer that might fall upon your code if you use a class.

Comment: that will also include _release_8_3_4 <-- i don't want that.... just 2 number e.g. _release_8_3

Comment: You can always filter those out... `$("[id$='_release_8_3']")` will get all the elements ending with the string, instead of simply containing the string.

Comment: Since the question aske for "get content of tag" if your are using jQuery don't forget to add the call to the text() function.

Comment: @Muffun You'd actualy need to loop through all the matching nodes found by the query, since `.innerHTML` and `.text()` will just concatenate all the contents of the elements together (see [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bq227dhL/)).

Comment: That document.querySelectorAll code doesn't work.

Comment: It does work.  I have edited my answer and added a code snippet that can be ran. You can see all the selectors found in the console output when running the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

e.g. _release_8_3

```
var string = 'release';
var number1 = 8;
var number2 = 3;
var selector = '#_'+ [ string, number1, number2 ].join( '_' );

var element = $(selector);
    element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element = document.getElementById('_'+ [ string, number1, number2 ].join( '_' ) );
```

Have you tried any of these?

If instead you are wanting to find all ids that match a pattern, use a class instead.  You can do pattern matching in lookups, however it is less performant and javascript will have to examine every single element in the dom to see if it matches your attribute pattern.  Instead by giving like patterned id elements the same class, you can perform a class lookup which, along with id and tagName lookups, are some of the fastest lookups your browser can perform.

Otherwise if you feel you absolutely must do this, I would instead try to steer you towards using one of the more efficient selectors, and then using filter to find what you want.  For instance in your example it looks like the pattern you gave is associated with h3 elements, so you could do.

```
$('h3').filter(function(){
    return /^[_]release[_][0-9]+[_][0-9]+$/.test(this.id);
});
```

Provided I got my regex right, this would find all the h3 elements and then filter to return only those that match the pattern `_release_#_#` where # is any number

Comment: I am loading a .html file 
var string = 'release';  <-- fixed
var number1 = 8;  <-- will change every time
var number2 = 3;  <-- will change every time

There are some ID in that file where id="_release_8_3_5"  <-- I don't want content of this .... just the content where there are only 1 string and 2 numbers e.g id="_release_8_2"

Comment: Wait, so you are not looking for a specific id, you want all that match a pattern?

Comment: YES... ID's that matches the pattern

Comment: Then use a class instead.  Avoid pattern matching for lookups

Comment: the file that I am loading is generated by ascii doctor (http://asciidoctor.org/) which creates tags by itself... and as a result I don't have access to modify the class .... even if I do.... I don't want to go back everytime I create the .html file from ascii doctor