# Javascript select span on parent span and use wildcard

Tags: javascript

I want to use JavaScript to select the `span` element with a `class` of `"price"`, but the selection has to be with the parent `span` with `id` "product-price-895". Additionally, I want to use a wildcard for the number part of the ID, so the selector has to be something like "#product-price-*"

```
<span  id="product-price-895"  data-price-amount="12.95" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper " >
<span class="price">€ 12,95</span>
</span>
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish exactly? Why can't you use the `price-wrapper` class instead of the partial id, or why not directly the `price` class?

Comment: The price wrapper occurs about 10 times, i only want to do something with the one that is enclosed by the one with the product-price-895

Comment: So you know the complete id. Then why the "wildcard" thing?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Have you read about [attribute-selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938294/select-div-using-wildcard-id

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("span[id^=product-price-]")` Would do the wildcard bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following CSS selector: `[id^=product-price] > .price`.

The selector uses a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) which means it is only concerned with elements having the class of `price` *that are an immediate child* of any element whose `id` attribute begins with `"product-price"` (due to the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax)).

```js
var spanEls = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=product-price] > .price');
spanEls.forEach(span => console.log(span.innerHTML));
```

```html
<span id="product-price-1" data-price-amount="12.95" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">€ 12,95</span>
</span>
<span id="product-price-2" data-price-amount="5.50" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">€ 5,50</span>
</span>
<span id="product-price-3" data-price-amount="25.90" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">€ 25,90</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors can handle this fairly easily: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

If you need to use vanilla JavaScript, you can use document.querySelector(): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want the child with the class "price" from the node with the id "product-price-895", you need to use the following css selector: `#product-price-895 > .price`.

In javascript I would use: `document.querySelector('#product-price-895 > .price')`.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the spans with the class `price` where the parent starts with `product-price-` you could use an [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^=`

```
$("span[id^=product-price-] span.price")
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span[id^=product-price-] span.price').forEach(x => console.log(x.innerHTML))
```

```html
<span id="product-price-895" data-price-amount="12.95" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper ">
<span class="price">€ 12,95</span>
<span class="price">€ 13,95</span>
<span class="prices">€ 14,95</span>
<span class="price">€ 15,95</span>
<span><span class="price">€ 18,95</span></span>
</span>
<span class="price">€ 16,95</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way may be to use an attribute selector instead of the ID. You could search by `document.querySelectorAll("[data-price-amount] > .price")` or `document.querySelectorAll("[data-price-type="finalPrice"] > .price")`. This will also give you a bit more control and flexibility if the way your IDs get generated changes in the future.