# Javascript select *id (with wildcard)

Tags: javascript

I have a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="entity__token" name="entity[_token]" value="SOMEVALUE" />
```

In my HTML the value of 'entity' in the attributes `name` and `id` could be anything, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="example__token" name="example[_token]" value="SOMEVALUE" />
```

I try to get the value of any kind of input field where the id ends with `__token`.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938294/select-div-using-wildcard-id) I tried:

```
var hiddenField = document.querySelector("[id^='__token']");
console.log(hiddenField.value);
```

That didn't work. I am looking for a solution without any jQuery.

Comment: Can you show how an actual name would look like?

Comment: The attribute selector you tried, `"[id^='__token']"`, selects elements whose `id` *starts* with the string you supplied. You're looking to identify elements whose `id` *ends* with that string: `"[id$='__token']"`

Comment: @LucaKiebel, anything like `id="some__token" name="some[_token]"` where 'some' can change. David's comment together with his comment of Roy's answer is of great help.

Comment: @DavidThomas unless you're struggling to find a duplicate that you're sure is there, I don't see why you shouldn't post your comment as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

`*` would work!

```js
var hiddenField = document.querySelector("[id*='__token']");
console.log(hiddenField.value);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="entity__token" name="entity[_token]" value="TtoNGqMMgMybh-JVttVSVWAOnyYe6s9eRnSOaBujtAE" />
```

[[attribute^=value]](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/css-selector-guide-google-tag-manager/#attribute-value-1)

> Matches if the element has the given attribute whose value starts with
>   the provided string.

vs.

[[attribute*=value]](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/css-selector-guide-google-tag-manager/#attribute-value-3)

> Matches if the element has the given attribute whose value contains
>   the provided string.

Comment: That appears to be the (unmodified) code from the question. If you can't reproduce the problem, say so in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Quentin it's not. The selector is different (`*` instead of `^`)

Comment: @Quentin Please do check. It is not.

Comment: After editing, it is now clear that it isn't … the answer would be a lot clearer with an explanation for what the difference between `^` and `*` means.

Comment: @Roy please next time don't over-format your answers. It's just distracting.

Comment: Bear in mind that the `[id*="__token']` selector you use would also match the (*highly improbable, but worth mentioning for future readers and **their** use cases*) values `]arbitraryString__token']arbitraryString` and `__token']]arbitraryString`.